# Copy Constructors and Polymorphism

Tags: java, constructor, copy-constructor

I have a class, which has subclasses for which I would like to handle copying objects properly. The superclass, called Item, has a copy constructor and the subclasses also have their own. However, what I want to know is to how to make it the following will work.

`Item` class (simplified description)

constructor:

```
public Item(...) {
}
```

copy constructor:

```
public Item( Item template ) {
}
```

- The basic layout the same for each subclass in this regard, excepting that at the moment they just make a new instance of item using a different constructor intended for making a new object from data stored in a text file (passing it data from the template object) and then fill in the additional fields from the template object.

The subclasses are things like Weapon, Armor, Shield, etc.

What I want to do is to able to say:

```
Weapon weapon = new Item( weapon );
```

Where weapon is a `Weapon` and the proper copy constructor (belonging to the specific subclass) is called, returning a new Object of type `Weapon`, as opposed to just getting back a new `Item` with only the `Item` parts that belonged to weapon. What is the best and/or right way to do this?

Comment: You likely want a [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). Although in your case I'm not really sure what the advantage of having a polymorphic constructor would be since you're interacting with the subclass `Weapon` rather than the base-class `Item`. If you know you're getting a `Weapon`, just call `Weapon()`.

Comment: You may be right on the factory pattern thing. I have a separate method elsewhere to create Item(s) from a template item and I want to generalize it rather than having a separate method for each subclass of Item which I'd have to right now, given that the classes have separate copy constructors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your copy constructor will be interacting with subclasses only, you should have abstract method for your copy constructor in the parent class and then define your copy constructors in child classes

Comment: As nice as that sounds, the Item class is not an abstract class, and nothing prevents you making an Item. It might be a design flaw issue, but Item covers any sort of Item that doesn't have a specific subclass. So, given that, I might want to copy just an ordinary Item and so an abstract copy constructor in the parent doesn't quite work.

Comment: Is it possible for you to modify your design so that, Items that do not have a specific subclass can have one common subclass? That way it would become a cleaner implementation.

Comment: An abstract class cannot have an abstract constructor in java.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the following line will never compile if `Weapon` is a subclass of `Item`.

```
Weapon weapon = new Item( weapon );
```

Instead of using a constructor, you can use a `static copy()` method in the `Item` class. Using the example below, each subclass must declare its own private copy constructor. These constructors are not visible to the outside world. Therefore, the only way to copy an `Item` is through `Item#copy()`.

**Item.java**

```
    public class Item {

    public String name;

    public Item(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private Item(Item template){
        this(template.name);
    }

    public static Item copy(Item template) {
        try {
            Class<? extends Item> clazz = template.getClass();
            Constructor<? extends Item> constructor = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(clazz);
            constructor.setAccessible(true);

            return constructor.newInstance(template);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**Weapon.java**

```
public class Weapon extends Item {

    double damage = 50.4;

    public Weapon(String name, double weight) {
        super(name);
        this.damage = weight;
    }

    private Weapon(Weapon template) {
        this(template.name, template.damage);
    }
}
```